# Snakemake: Is it possible to only display "Job counts" using --dryrun?

Tags: snakemake

How can I make Snakemake display only the `Job counts` fields on a dry run? When performing a real run, that's the first information Snakemake outputs before starting the jobs.

Currently, the way I get job counts is to run Snakemake without the `-n` flag and immediately cancel it (`^C`), but that's far from ideal.

Letting the dry run complete will output the `Job counts` at the end, but that's not feasible for pipelines with hundreds or thousands of jobs.

Desired output:

```
$ snakemake -n --someflag
Job counts:
        count   jobs
        504     BMO
        1       all
        504     fit_nbinoms
        517     motifs_in_peaks
        503     motifs_outside_peaks
        2029
$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flag `-q`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executable.html#OUTPUT) does this.

```
--quiet, -q    Do not output any progress or rule information.
```

Comment: It took the same time as waiting for `--dryrun` to finish (3+ mins) and I got an empty output. Were you able to get the `Job counts` in your machine? If so, what Snakemake version are you using?

Comment: I see exact output as in your example when I use `-q` flag. I use `v5.4.0` on Mac. In any case, I would think snakemake needs to complete dag to figure out jobs that need to be run, and therefore `-q` flag would still take the same amount of time to show the jobs and their count. It's purpose is to simplify the output and not the processing time.